# Reading views from SQL through RODBC package

Tags: sql-server-2008, r, view, rodbc

Through the RODBC function *odbcConnect* we connected R with a SQL Express 2008 database.

Importing tables in R  is quite easy using the *sqlFetch* function

```
 sqlFetch(channel, sqtable, ..., colnames = FALSE, rownames = TRUE)
```

In case we wanted instead to read and import a **SQL view** how can we do then?

Answer (score 2):

From the [RODBC PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf):

> Note the ‘table’ includes whatever table-like objects are provided by
>   the DBMS, in particular views and system tables

So, it does appear that views are treated as tables by the system.